# How was the below equation derived for "extremising" the function $\lambda(x)=\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Background: in Bence, Hobson, Riley Mathematical Methods pg.291, the authors are showing  another way to find the maximum eigenvalue problem by maximizing $\lambda(x)=\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$. The first line doesn't make sense to me and I can't figure out how it was formed. Equation 1 is all I'm confused about but I included the whole example in case I left out an important detail: 
[image]

Comment: In general, we have $$\left(\frac{N(x)}{D(x)}\right)' = \frac{N'(x)}{D(x)} - N(x)\frac{D'(x)}{D(x)}
= \frac{D(x)N'(x)-N(x)D'(x)}{D(x)^2}$$
Now replace $N(x)$ by $x^TAx$ and $D(x)$ by $x^Tx$ and throw away higher order terms proportional to $\Delta x^2, \ldots$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient